# Can't find the minimum in an array with respect to maximum from the same array

Tags: c++, sorting, c++17, runtime-error, swap

I wanted to write a program to take two arrays as input and convert the first array such that the difference of maximum value and minimum value from the first array gives the smallest possible number.

I tried to write a code to find a smaller number most closest to the maximum from the array in C++, but the function for finding the minimum works on Codelite, but not on other compilers;
Is there any fix to solve this, either to the code or the compiler?

Here is the code I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void swap(int A[], int B[], int n)
{
    int x, y, temp;
    
    for(x=0;x<n;++x)
    {
        for(y=0;y<n;++y)
        {
            if(A[x]>B[y])
            {
                temp = A[x];
                A[x] = B[y];
                B[y] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void sortas(int A[], int n)
{
    int i, j, temp;
    
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = i; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (A[i] > A[j+1])
            {
                temp = A[i];
                A[i] = A[j+1];
                A[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int maxfind(int A[], int n)
{
    int z, a;
    
    a = A[0];
    for(z=0;z<n;++z)
    {
        if(a<A[z])
        {
            a = A[z];
        }
    }
    
    cout << "Max value in A is" << a << endl;
    
    return a;
}

int minfind(int A[], int n, int amax, int amin)
{
    int z, maxi;
    maxi = amax;
    for(z=0;z<n;++z)
    {
        if(maxi >= A[z])
        {
            amin = A[z];
        }
        else
        {
            maxi = maxi-1;
        }
    }
    cout << "Mix value in A is" << amin << endl;
    
    return amin;
}


int main() {
    
    int z, t;
    cout << "Enter number of test cases: ";
    cin >> t;
    
    int n, i, j, amax, amin;

    for(z=0;z<t;++z)
    {
        cout << "Enter size of array" << endl;
        cin >> n;
        
        int A[n], B[n];
        
        cout << "Enter Array A values:" << endl;
        for(i=0;i<n;++i)
        {
            cin >> A[i];
        }
        
        cout << "Enter Array B values:" << endl;
        for(j=0;j<n;++j)
        {
            cin >> B[j];
        }
        
        swap(A, B, n);
        sortas(A, n);
        
        cout << "Swapped and sorted array is: " << endl;
        for(i=0;i<n;++i)
        {
            cout << A[i] << "\t" << B[i] << endl;
        }
        amax = 0;
        amin = 0;
        amax = maxfind(A, n);
        amin = minfind(A, n, amax, amin);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output to that code:

> 1 1 1 3 4 2
>
> Max value in A is 1 Min value in A is 1
>
> 1 2 2
> -1882830412 4 3 6 3
>
> Max value in A is 2 Min value in A is -1882830412

Comment: You should use std::min, std::max, std::sort, std::swap

Comment: *'convert the first array such that the difference of maximum value and minimum value from the first array gives the smallest possible number.'* -- Can you elaborate on what it means? Otherwise, just convert all numbers in the array to the same number, like `0`, and the difference between largest and smallest will just be 0.

Comment: Sorry, if I wasn't clear, but the final goal is to swap the elements from both the arrays to the first array such that the result can be the smallest integer. The outputs are already fixed so to display 0 on all test cases wouldn't really help in my case. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your bubble sort:

```
void sortas(int A[], int n)
{
    int i, j, temp;
    
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = i; j < n; j++)  // why not start at i + 1 ??
        {
            if (A[i] > A[j+1])   // j + 1 is out of bounds when j == n - 1
            {
                temp = A[i];
                A[i] = A[j+1];  // <-- Some random value is written to A.
                A[j+1] = temp;  // <-- Overwriting some variable on the stack    
                                //     of main() (possibly B ?)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A correct bubble sort (this is *not* the pedantic bubble sort), this is probably the most used.

```
void sortas(int A[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j)
        {
            if (A[i] > A[j])
                std::swap(A[i], A[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

The actual bubble sort algorithn (the "pedantic" bubble sort), swaps only occur on neighboring values.

```
void sortas(int A[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < (n - i) - 1; ++j)
        {
            if (A[j] > A[j + 1])
                std::swap(A[j], A[j + 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Use one or the other, for integers, the performance is identical.

Comment: Really thanks for the answer! I am a novice to C++ so I still am learning the std swap and other functions. Thanks again